# Are periods in a service name considered “special characters” for tinydns and daemontools?

Tags: centos, daemontools, tinydns, djbdns

I'm building some new DNS servers which will run [tinydns](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns.html). I need to run two instances of tinydns on each server, each serving what is our production authoritative DNS and a legacy authoritative DNS which is being phased out, i.e.:

```
ns0.production.foo.net
ns0.legacy.bar.net
```

I want to clearly identify these by their names and create their services by running:

```
tinydns-conf tinydns tinydnslogs /etc/tinydns/ns0.production.foo.net 172.16.3.100
```

and:

```
tinydns-conf tinydns tinydnslogs /etc/tinydns/ns0.legacy.bar.net 172.16.3.101
```

(and then obviously sym-linking to these folders in `/services` for the daemontools magic)

The documentation for [`tinydns-conf`](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tinydns-conf.html) states that:

> #### Interface
>
> ```
>  tinydns-conf acct logacct D ip
> ```
>
> tinydns-conf creates a service directory D that runs tinydns. **The
> name D must start with a slash and must not contain any special
> characters.**

Are periods considered "special characters" in tinydns/daemontools service names?

I've tested tinydns with service names containing periods and nothing appears to be untoward, will I be ok?

I'm running CentOS 6.7 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted more or less the same question to the tinydns mailing list:

> http://marc.info/?t=144662485500001&r=1&w=2

The consensus is that periods are probably fine, but be careful of:

**Using spaces:**

> from the source of tiny*.c files, I can’t see a certain restriction.
>
> However, I would not not directory names with white spaces here [(source)](http://marc.info/?l=djbdns&m=144666857406994&w=2)

**Shell meta-characters:**

> I think you ought to be safe if you interpret "special characters" as
>   shell meta characters. [(source)](http://marc.info/?l=djbdns&m=144667004607368&w=2)

Other thoughts:

> In the respective case the dot ‚.‘ in the file name might be
>   interpreted as RegEx (one wildcard character) on the shell. Since the
>   ‚dot‘ itself is recursively included I would not expect any harm.
>   However, either correct quoting of the file name or escaping the ‚dot‘
>   is always a good idea.
>
> Thus DJB’s statement is a warning, not a restriction. [(source)](http://marc.info/?l=djbdns&m=144667134907759&w=2)